# Rails create action not working, submitting nil values?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

Working on a Rails app that submits form data through an AJAX PUT request, and somehow I broke things along the way because it used to work fine. Let me start by showing you the error message I get in my console:

```
Started POST "/submissions" for 98.245.21.165 at 2013-09-25 18:10:49 +0000                                                                                     
Processing by SubmissionsController#create as JSON                                                                                                             
Parameters: {"title"=>"I'll be up in marikesh", "content"=>"Yup", "folder_id"=>"1"}                                                                          
User Load (86.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1                                                                             
(86.3ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                             
SQL (178.9ms)  INSERT INTO "submissions" ("content", "created_at", "folder_id", "parent_id", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6
, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["content", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 25 Sep 2013 18:10:50 UTC   +00:00], ["folder_id", nil], ["parent_id", nil], ["title", nil], ["update
d_at", Wed, 25 Sep 2013 18:10:50 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]                                                                                                
(90.9ms)  COMMIT                                                                                                                                            
(85.9ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                             
(86.3ms)  COMMIT                                                                                                                                            
Rendered submissions/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)                                                                                      
Completed 200 OK in 701ms (Views: 52.6ms | ActiveRecord: 614.3ms)
```

So as you can see my form and routes work because the correct action was initiated and the params were passed. However, the params aren't being submitted into a new instance of the model.

Here's my create action:

```
def create 

ajax_title = params[:title]
  ajax_content = params[:content]
  ajax_folder = params[:folder_id]
ajax_parent = params[:parent_id]
  ajax_children = params[:children]

@submissions = Submission.where(title: ajax_title)

if @submissions.empty?
  @submission = Submission.create({title: ajax_title, content: ajax_content, user_id: current_user.id, folder_id: ajax_folder, parent_id: ajax_parent, children: ajax_children})
else
  @submissions[0].content = ajax_content
  @submissions[0].save
end

end
```

And here's my AJAX form:

```
$("#save-entry").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/submissions",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {title: $("#title-create-partial").text(), content: $("#content-create-partial").text(), folder_id: <%= @folder.id %>},
                complete: function(){
                    $.get("/ajax_load_events/", {folder: <%= @folder.id %>}, null, "script");
                }
            });
        });
```

I even checked my submission.rb model and all the attributes are attr_accessible, so that shouldn't be the problem. Any ideas what happened here? Suggestions on how I could change/improve my create action would also be appreciated. I don't actually need to check for uniqueness (the user should be able to create multiple submissions with the same title), so if you have any suggestions on how I can simplify the action, that would also be appreciated.

Here's submission.rb:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :content, :title, :user_id, :folder_id, :parent_id, :children

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :folder
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Submission'
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Submission', :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :order => ('updated_at DESC')

def self.search(search)
    if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
        scoped
    end
end

def attributes_with_children
    attributes.merge(children: children.map(&:attributes_with_children))
end

end
```

Added `logger.info(@submission.inspect)` and got this output:

```
Started POST "/submissions" for 98.245.21.165 at 2013-09-25 18:56:23 +0000                                                                                                
Processing by SubmissionsController#create as JSON                                                                                                                        
Parameters: {"title"=>"test", "content"=>"test", "folder_id"=>"1"}                                                                                                      
User Load (77.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1                                                                                        
(83.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."title" = 'test'                                                                                      
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 181ms                                                                                                                              

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):                                                                                                                 
  app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

I raked my routes, here they are:http://pastebin.com/gdfthakg

Comment: Can you post the result of `rake routes`? I am wondering if your route has `/submissions` as a POST action

Comment: I'm not going to post it because it's a little long, but yes, there is a POST action for that route.

Comment: The server log doesn't seem to show any error message actually, `Parameters: {"title"=>"I'll be up in marikesh", "content"=>"Yup", "folder_id"=>"1"}`. It seems like parameters are passed to server as well.

Comment: By the way, do you have `attr_accessible :title, :content, :folder_id` in your model?

Comment: @JasonKim - You're right, but as you can see the created submission just comes back nil for all those attributes. I'll post the model.

Comment: Okay, added submission.rb

Comment: Try adding `logger.info(@submission.inspect)` directly after the create line in the controller and post what you get back.

Comment: Why aren't you using Rails to do the AJAX submission for you? I bet there is something fishy with the way you are doing it manually that Rails fails to understand

Comment: My guess is that you're params are not being picked up in the create action properly. I.e. `ajax_title = params[:title]` always returns nil.

Comment: @beautifulcoder - I'm using HTML5 contenteditable divs for the inputs, so I couldn't think of another way to send the data to the backend.

Comment: @tommaxwell OK, take that line out now and replace it with this `logger.info(ajax_title.inspect)` and update with the log info.

Comment: Try changing `ajax_title = params[:title]` to  `ajax_title = params['title']`

Comment: @BetjaminRichards - Same error message as before, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your AJAX request format. If you take a look at your routes:

```
submissions GET    /submissions(.:format)  submissions#index
            POST   /submissions(.:format) submissions#create
```

It is expecting a `.format`. So for JSON it should be `/submissions.json`. The framework is designed to take care of this for you but since you are doing it manually it looks like you might have to be more specific.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try and see what happens